# [Spark][DataFrame] Most elegant way to calculate 1st dayofWeek

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have data in a DataFrame with a column as `DateTime`. Now I wish to find out the first day of the the week , First day means MONDAY.

So I have thought of the following Ways to achieve this -

- With an arithmetic Calculation:

  `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`

  `val df1 = Seq((1, "2020-05-12 10:23:45", 5000), (2, "2020-11-11 12:12:12", 2000)).toDF("id", "DateTime", "miliseconds")`

  `val new_df1=df1.withColumn("week",date_sub(next_day(col("DateTime"),"monday"),7))`

  **Result -**
  [image]

- Creating an UDF which does the similar activity ( This is of least priority )
- `df1.withColumn("week", date_trunc("week", $"DateTime"))`

If there are any more methods to achieve this, I would like to see more implementations.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What more elegant way then the `date_trunc` function are you looking for?

Comment: I already answered here the best performant way - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62690896/4758823. Any reason you are asking other way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-05-12 10:23:45' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62689666/caused-by-java-time-format-datetimeparseexception-text-2020-05-12-102345-c)

Comment: @TomLous, Someshwar . Thanks For helping me , so are there any other implementations possible too ? I am new to Spark-Scala and I want to know what are the various implementations for a particular task so that I can evaluate which to use and where. You need not give a definite answer, just help me with a direction and I will work on another implementation .